# Keychain and iOS version upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid, keychain, udid

Soon or right at the moment will be a lot of iOS updates.
So i have a question about Keychain items stored with my application.
I know what item will stay even if application will be removed, but not sure about iOS update.

My question is:
Will Keychain item stored by my application stay on device since user have update their device iOS version (from iOS 7 to iOS 8 as example)?

Answer (score 1):

Key Chain items will remain until and otherwise you explicitly change the keychain items from your executable code and with the application having the same application identifier.

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH204-TP9)

> On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to
>   sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same
>   provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

Comment: But if i press "Restore to default device settings" in Settings app will lost keychaing items?

Comment: This is a little off topic from the initial question, but... So, provisioning profiles expire in one year. Does this mean that necessarily, you can't keep access to keychain data in your app, across version updates, for more than a year? E.g., say I release versions 1.0 on Jan 18, 2015. Then continue successive updates to the app with versions 1.1, 1.2 etc. All using the same provisioning profile. What happens with a version of the app released on Jan 19, 2016? Will it necessarily lose access to the prior keychain data?

Comment: @EvgeniyS yes. if you choose the option."Erase all content and settings". It will clear the keychain item also.

Comment: @ChrisPrince If the  profile is the same expired profile (just that their expiry date is updated)and signed with the same certificate, then the same app would be able to access its older keychain.